# Schema.org terms can act both as properties or types?

Tags: schema.org

I installed an RDF module on my Drupal 8 site and it seems that I can pick the exact options from the exact same list for both [Content types](https://www.drupal.org/node/21947) (Drupal concept) as well as for [fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_(computer_science)).

It seems quite wired to me as I was sure that the terms using for S.org properties and the terms using for S.org types are different from one another.

Either each term can act both as a property or type, or otherwise I can't explain it.

Comment: Your assumption is correct, Schema.org types are not supposed to be used as properties, and vice-versa (however, I guess technically/formally they could be used for anything in RDF -- but it wouldn’t make sense to do this). -- Does this mean you can select, e.g., `name` as type for a content type? Are you only using core modules, or also https://www.drupal.org/project/rdfui or something else?

Comment: It seems I had a mistake, the lists mistakenly seemed to me to be identical... I should delete the question and edit my report at D.O thanks for you help and suggestion to check both lists with the "Name" property.

Comment: I also thought the Hierarchy is property-type when its actually type-property...

Comment: BTW @unor , What do you think is the best practice when picking SO type for a Drupal content-type ? I assume picking one single SO type for all Drupal content-types is best but I might be wrong. What do you think ?

Comment: The power of Drupal’s content type system is that you can have different "templates" for different content (a page about a person needs different fields/layout/URL path/etc. than a page about a book). Why would you throw away this advantage when mapping to Schema.org? A content type that represents a book should have the type `Book`, a content type that represents a blog post should have the type `BlogPosting`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption is correct. Schema.org types (aka. classes) are not supposed to be used as properties, and vice-versa. (Technically they could be used for anything, but it wouldn’t make sense to do this.)

But the [RDF UI](https://www.drupal.org/project/rdfui) module is doing it correctly:

- When editing a content type, you can select (under "Schema.org Mappings") a type:

  > Specify the type you want to associated to this content type e.g. Article, Blog, etc.

  The autocomplete list correctly lists/suggests types, i.e., terms that start with an uppercase letter (like `Thing`).
- When mapping a field (under "Manage fields" → "RDF Mappings"), you can select a property.

  The autocomplete list correctly lists/suggests properties, i.e., terms that start with a lowercase letter (like `name`).

If you have a content type "Team member", you could map it to the Schema.org type `Person`, and the field "Title" could be mapped to the Schema.org property `name`.

#### Background

Note that it’s just a convention (followed by Schema.org and many other vocabularies) to start types with uppercase letters, and properties with lowercase letters. A vocabulary could as well use `x8234` for a type and `x8238` for a property.

If something is supposed to be a type or a property should ideally become clear in the vocabulary’s documentation, but the canonical definition can be found in the vocabulary’s RDF.

In case of Schema.org ([canonical definition in RDFa](http://schema.org/docs/schema_org_rdfa.html)), you can see that `name` is of type [`rdf:Property`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-rdf-schema-20140225/#ch_property):

> ```html
> <div typeof="rdf:Property" resource="http://schema.org/name"> 
>   <!-- … -->
> </div>
> ```

and `Person` is of type [`rdfs:Class`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-rdf-schema-20140225/#ch_class):

> ```html
> <div typeof="rdfs:Class" resource="http://schema.org/Person">
>   <!-- … -->
> </div>
> ```

Comment: Unor, small comment-level question, if it's okay: To give a S.org type for my homepage, I created a whole new content-type for it... What do you think is the best type for that? I gave it "ProfessionalService" as my website represents services I give. Is there something generic you choose for homepage content-types? I ask for general knowledge. Much thanks for everything.

Comment: Gonna give you the bounty for this professional answer btw... :) The system allows me to do so in about 23 hours...

Comment: @Benia: Thank you. Regarding your question about type(s) for the homepage: Sometime I use `WebSite` with the topic the website is about in `about` (e.g., `WebSite` `about` `Thing`), possibly with `WebPage` (which I typically use on every page) in addition -- where `Thing` is typically an `Organization` (if it’s a company’s website) or `Person` (if it’s a personal website) etc. -- Note that `ProfessionalService` is deprecated; in most cases, `Service` might be used instead.